# Updating results in 404 errors for everything - 404 not found ip

Tags: updates, software-sources

I'm running ubuntu 21.10 and trying to update and then upgrade.

unfortunatelly

```
sudo apt update
```

i get the following errors:

```
Ign:1 http://.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease                 
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease                   
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Ign:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt impish-pgdg InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Err:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt impish-pgdg Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:4800:3e1:1::246 80]
Err:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Ign:1 http://.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Ign:1 http://.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Err:1 http://.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve '.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt impish-pgdg Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

also running the following command:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

produces the following output...

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

also please not the file /etc/apt/sources.list is empty....

any help?

thank you very much!

Comment: the issue is that 21.04 is EOL and therefore the sources have been moved to old-releases.ubuntu.com

Comment: In the future, upgrade your OS *before* the EOL date to avoid such situations.

Comment: I changed all the urls to old-release, and did the update + upgrade... unfortunatelly postgresql in not upgrading and I believe this is why the do-release-upgrade command is not working "please install all the available updates..."

Comment: you may have to uninstall postgresql, do the upgrade, and then install it again. Be sure to back up your databases if you need them still.

Comment: yes, it looks like postgresql no longer has the repos for EOL versions available. In general, postgres is available from the regular Ubuntu repos, you can install it from there

Comment: found the script to update postgres source.list on their website [link](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/).

Comment: Now I'm upgrading correclty :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades